# App has messed up widgets in different devices

Tags: flutter

I've made an app to display graphs and charts. When I test it on my device, the UI is fine. But then, I installed the app on another device, and the UI was messed up. The font size was too high, there were pixels overflowing, etc.

How do I fix this?

For pixel overflowing, I suppose I could wrap my widgets in SafeArea. That should hopefully work, but what about the different font sizes?

Answer (score 1):

To solve that you can use Media Query to adjust the font size based on the height of the device:

Just to exemplify, here a huge title on AppBar:

```
AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Text('TITLE', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100),),
),
```

[image]

Now, using MediaQuery to get the height of the device:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(
        'TITLE',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: height <= 800 ? 30 : 100), //if less or equal to 800 fontSize will be 30, else, 100. 
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

You can use MediaQuery to set the size of everything in your app, but you have other ways to do that with other widgets, for example, with the Flexible widget:

Without Flexible:

```
  body: Center(
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
            'I will overflow, just wait, i will overflow, just wait,'
                ' i will overflow, just wait,  i will overflow, just wait'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

[image]

With Flexible:

```
Flexible(
     child: Text(
          'I will overflow, just wait, i will overflow, just wait,'
           ' i will overflow, just wait,  i will overflow, just wait'),
        ),
```

[image]